# change delay for touch:longpress in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, touch, fabricjs, long-press

I will change delay for longpress in fabric.js (build with eventjs), but it no change. what am I doing wrong?

```
canvas.on('touch:longpress', longPress, {
        delay: 5000
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to `eventjs` like this.

```
eventjs.add({
  target: canvas.upperCanvasEl,
  type: 'longpress',
  delay: 5000,
  listener: function(event, self) {
    console.log(self.fingers);
  }
});
```